# Software for generating sewing patterns from 3D model for furniture

Tags: furniture

I'm looking for a free (haha) or inexpensive tool to unfold/unroll 3D models to get sewing patterns for fabrics. Think couch or chairs upholstery with foam inside.

[ExactFlat](https://www.exactflat.com/) is a professional tool that does just this. For hobby / starting a business this is way too expensive and also has an overkill of functions.
I have read the unfold function of Rhino isn't really suitable/accurate for making (complex) sewing patterns.

- Is it possible in Rhino, is there other software out there or would you advice another technique to create patterns?

Simple couch cushions is something I would like to start with and ultimately I would like to try and make something as complex as this chair:

[image]

Comment: Several potential alternatives to ExactFlat CAD software are mentioned here:  https://www.sculpteo.com/en/3d-learning-hub/3d-printing-software/solidworks-alternatives/  I've used a few on the list, but never to produce anything like what you need to do, so I can't actually give an "answer" about which software packages can do what, or how easily, etc.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. How this sort of thing was done traditionally is still an option. While (obviously!) slower it still works just as it used to, but of course with the usual downsides for someone coming it at ground level.

Comment: I am closing this question since it is not about woodwork within the context of this site. Please take the [tour](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/tour) top learn more about how we work.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, if this question is closed, it would be migrated to an appropriate location.

[Pepakura Designer](https://tamasoft.co.jp/pepakura-en/productinfo/index.html) will do as you suggest. Aimed primarily to paper crafters, it takes a 3D design, flattens it and provides fold/cut/glue location. US$38 for a license seems inexpensive.

> Pepakura Designer supports common 3DCG file formats, including OBJ,
> 3DS, and STL

Comment: *If* it's closed? :-) In addition to two obvious issues, it's not helped any by the chair the OP chose as their example almost certainly having no wooden parts!

Comment: Oh, yeah, that might play a part. A migration to Software Recommendations seems appropriate.